# Handling a connection server-multiclient gives the error: Connection reset by peer: socket write error in a SocketException

Tags: java, server, client, client-server, tcpclient

Goodmorning everyone,
For a uni project I have to create a multithread server-client system.
I've got some problems during the connection between a client and the server: when the server runs and I execute the client, the connection is working. 
 - Anyway, when the client logs out the server crashes repeating the same error over and over again.
I use a ClientHandler to handle the multithread connection, and the error its at line 60.
Here there are the three classes:

Server class

```
public class Server {

private static final int SPORT = 5056;
private static ArrayList<Thread> ThreadAttivi = new ArrayList<Thread>() {
};
private static ArrayList<Impiegato> ImpiegatiLoggati = new ArrayList<Impiegato>() {
};
private Socket s;

public Server() {
    InetAddress ip;
    try {
        ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        this.s = null;
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void runServer() throws IOException, InterruptedException

{

    // inizializzazione dei dipendenti
    Funzionario f = new Funzionario("mario", "super", "funzionario", "Ferrari", "Via cavallotti", 3, "2012-03-01",
            "ciao");
    Impiegato f2 = new Funzionario("gino", "gini", "funzionario", "Fiat", "Via lattea", 33, "2012-03-01", "hi");
    Impiegato f3 = new Funzionario("paolo", "bitta", "funzionario", "Lancia", "Via davanti", 1, "2012-03-01",
            "bye");
    Impiegato f4 = new Funzionario("tea", "tea", "funzionario", "Audi", "Via Mascagni", 2, "2012-03-01", "salut");

    // server is listening on port 5056
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SPORT);

    System.out.println("In ascolto sulla porta:" + SPORT);

    // running infinite loop for getting
    // client request
    long beginning = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long end = beginning + 30000;

    while (true) // dopo un tot di tempo smettiamo di ascoltare e partono le funzioni randomiche
    {

        s = null;

        try {

            s = serverSocket.accept();

            {
                // socket object to receive incoming client requests

                System.out.println("A new client is connected : " + s);

                // obtaining input and out streams
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

                System.out.println("Assigning new thread for this client");

                // create a new thread object
                Thread t = new ClientHandler(dis, dos, s);

                // Invoking the start() method
                t.start();
                ThreadAttivi.add(t);

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            s.close();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new Server().runServer();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} }
```

Client class:

```
public class Client {
private static final int SPORT = 5056;
private PrintWriter output;
private BufferedReader read;
private Socket s;
private ObjectInputStream in;
private ObjectOutputStream os;
private InetAddress ip;

public Client() {

    try {
        this.ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        this.s = new Socket(ip, SPORT);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void run() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {

    try {
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        //this.in = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        this.os = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
        this.os.flush();

        // getting localhost ip

        // establish the connection with server port 5056

        // obtaining input and out streams
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        // the following loop performs the exchange of
        // information between client and client handler
        while (true) {

            // l'user scrive username e password al ClientHandler
            System.out.println(dis.readUTF()); // leggiamo dal ClientHandler
            String username = scn.nextLine(); // scriviamo da console username
            dos.writeUTF(username); // inviamo il dato al ClientHandler

            System.out.println(dis.readUTF());
            String password = scn.nextLine();
            dos.writeUTF(password);
            // l'user riceve una risposta

            String received = dis.readUTF();

            if (received.equals("Dati sbagliati")) {
                System.out.println("Closing this connection : " + s);
                System.out.println("Dati sbagliati");
                scn.close();
                dis.close();
                dos.close();
                s.close();
                break;
            }
            else if (received.equals("Already logged")) {
                System.out.println("Closing this connection : " + s);
                System.out.println("Utente già connesso");
                scn.close();
                dis.close();
                dos.close();
                s.close();
                break;
            }
            else if (received.equals("loggato")) {
                System.out.println("Sei connesso!!!\nCosa vuoi fare?");
                //Object userLogged = (Impiegato)in.readObject();
                //if (userLogged instanceof Funzionario) {
                //  Funzionario funz = (Funzionario) userLogged;
                //  Funzionario.funzioneRandom(funz);
                    break;
                }
            else System.out.println("no opzioni");

            // printing date or time as requested by client

            // System.out.println(received);
        }

        // closing resources
        scn.close();
        dis.close();
        dos.close();
        in.close();
        os.close();
        s.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Client client = new Client();
    client.run();

}}
```

ClientHandler class:

```
public class ClientHandler extends Thread {

private static ArrayList<ClientHandler> ListaClientHandler = new ArrayList<ClientHandler>() {};
private static ArrayList<Impiegato> ImpiegatiLoggati = new ArrayList<Impiegato>() {};
private boolean already_registered = false;
private boolean dati_sbagliati = false;
private boolean impiegato_loggato = false;
final DataInputStream dis;
final DataOutputStream dos;
private Socket client;
private int bytesRead;
private Connect c = new Connect();
private BufferedReader input;
private PrintWriter output;
private static final long SLEEPTIME = 2000;
private Impiegato curr_impiegato;

private Funzionario curr_funzionario;

// caricamento dei dati nel ClientHandler
private static ArrayList<Impiegato> Impiegati = Impiegato.getListaImpiegati();

// Constructor
public ClientHandler(DataInputStream dis, DataOutputStream dos, Socket client) {
    this.dis = dis;
    this.dos = dos;
    this.client = client;
    ListaClientHandler.add(this);
}

public static ArrayList<ClientHandler> getListaCH() {
    return ListaClientHandler;
}

public static void setListaImpiegati(ArrayList<ClientHandler> listaCH) {
    ListaClientHandler = listaCH;
}

// QUESTO E' IL NOSTRO
// SISTEMA-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

@Override
public void run() {
    String username;
    String password;
    String toreturn;

    while (true) {
        try {

            dos.writeUTF("Username:\n"); // Ask user the username
            username = dis.readUTF(); // receive the answer from client

            dos.writeUTF("password:\n"); // Ask user the password
            password = dis.readUTF(); // receive the answer from client

            // invio differenti messaggi a seconda del risultato del login

            if (checkLog(username, password)) // se si è loggato
            {

                impiegato_loggato = true;
                System.out.println("Client " + this.client + " è loggato...");
                dos.writeUTF("loggato");
                while (ListaClientHandler.size() != ImpiegatiLoggati.size()) {
                    // System.out.println("Waiting");
                }
                dos.writeUTF("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz");
                this.dopoAccesso();
                break;
            } else if (dati_sbagliati) // comunico che ci sono errori nell'inserimento dei dati
            {
                dos.writeUTF("Dati sbagliati");
                ListaClientHandler.remove(this);
                client.close();
                break;
            }

            else if (already_registered) {
                dos.writeUTF("Already logged");
                client.close();
                break;
            }

        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

and this is the error message:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(DataOutputStream.java:401)
at java.base/java.io.DataOutputStream.writeUTF(DataOutputStream.java:323)
at progettoAzienda.ClientHandler.run(ClientHandler.java:60)
```

Comment: It seems like the `Client` program returned, before the server could send data. You should make sure that the client stays up, and its connections stay open. Obviously, it the client program returns, then socket writes will fail on the server side.

Comment: @Daniele thank you for the answer, can you please explain it using code ?